# If a list-item has a span inside, bring that item to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, this might be a bit difficult to explain, but I hope you do understand something at least.

My intention is to make a jQuery checkup if a <**li**> has a <**span**> in it, and if so, it gathers a new list of these items with that span in them to my front page, to a totally different element. I've tried various checkups and such, but not with any sort of succession.

Here is the element I'm trying to check up for the span's:

```
<div class="reviewList">
   <ul id="myList" class="list-group">
      <li><a href="#">Example 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Example 2</a> <span class="label">New</span></li>
      <li><a href="#">Example 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Example 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Example 5</a> <span class="label">New</span></li>
      <li><a href="#">Example 6</a> <span class="label">New</span></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

And so, how am I going to get a list of those to my website's front page to another list. I'm trying to create a list of new items to the front page, which are in the another list marked up as "New" labels.

Thank you for any assistance to this, appreciate it!

Comment: where is your attempts made out of JS..?

Comment: There's nothing to really post about, and yet again I'm not in any case advanced with jQuery/js, that's why I need help with this, goes too complicated.

Comment: You want to gather these items and bring them to your homepage? Meaning, let's say you are in the page, for example, 'myLists.html', then gather the items and bring them to 'index.html'? Is that right?

Comment: The reason i'm asking this is because you will need to store these items somewhere because they won't survive a page refresh

Comment: Well I'm able to create a hidden field for that in my page, which uses Bootstrap, not a big of an issue.

Comment: Even with a hiddenfield, that data won't be reusable once a page refresh will occur...

Comment: It actually will be, if it's being hidden with the same jQuery, after getting that information.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a bit of Jquery and a data storage helper like [JStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/).

jStorage supports storing Strings, Numbers, JavaScript objects, Arrays, native XML nodes.

RGS already gave you a good head start. Now you need to store that data with JStorage. On the Document Ready event in 'homepage.html', you will be able to fetch that stored data and append it to your list.

```
//SET data
$.jStorage.set(key, value, options);

//GET data
value = $.jStorage.get(key)
```